# Drupal display View in a custom page of a theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I create a new theme in Drupal. I need to display a view in custom page but i don't want to use the region. I need the php code that we add it to the tpl page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `views_embed_view` within your template. The first parameter is the collective name for the Views and the second is the display name.

`<?php echo views_embed_view('myview', 'block'); ?>`